# How to use fscanf to detect line breaks?

Tags: matlab

I am using fscanf to import data into MATLAB. My text file is formatted as such:

```
 ######-10-K-########
 ######-10-K-########
```

The first number can vary anywhere from 6-9 characters. Right now I am using the code:

```
 var = fcanf(fn, %s)
```

which is resulting in var being equal to one giant string.

I read that using %s will go on until it detects a whitespace. Is there anyone to get it to stop when it detects a linebreak instead?

Comment: What part of the data do you actually want to import? The whole lines as individual strings? Only the numbers and the letters?

Comment: Just adapt your [`format specifier`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec) to your data: `fscanf(fn,'%f-10-K-%f'`. Or if you use textscan as in the answer below: `file_data = textscan(f, '%f-10-K-%f');`. Replace `%f` by `%d` if you expect only integral numbers.

Comment: putting an star `*` character in a format specifier tells Matlab to ignore this entry, so in your case use:  `%f-10-K-%*f\n`

Comment: @Hoki So, and sorry to keep bothering you, I realize the original code you posted was not capturing the -10-K, but rather creating double the entries. If my line read "123456789-10-K-87654321" it would create a 2x1 matrix of entries 123456789, and 87654321. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Well that's what I understood your question was, just pick up the numeric values. Do you **want** to retrieve the `-10-K-` part ? Or just ignore them ?

Comment: Yea I would like to retain the -10-K- part. So each element is "%f-10-K-%f"

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has many functions, you can use `textscan` for example. Note that using `textscan` as follows trims all spaces in each line.

```
f = fopen('your_file_name');
file_data = textscan(f, '%s', 'Delimiter', '');
fclose(f);
```

Another example with `fgetl` as follows. `fgetl` keeps indents and spaces in each line.

```
lineCt = 1;
f = fopen('your_file_name');
tline = fgetl(f);
while ischar(tline)
    f_data{lineCt} = tline;
    lineCt = lineCt + 1;
    tline = fgetl(f);
end
fclose(f);
```

Note that it should be `fscanf` instead of `fcanf` as you wrote.

Comment: Sorry, typo there. Now it is returning a 1x1 matrix with only the first line. Any thoughts?

Comment: try `fclose('all')` and repeat. It should give you a cell array with each cell contains one line from your file.

Comment: do you have `Notepad++`? Use it to open your text file and check which ascii keys are used for `new line`. Normally, pressing `Enter` will be `CR LF`, which means `Carriage Return Line Feed`, and corresponding to `Delimiter = \r\n` in Matlab.

Comment: I use Textwrangler and made sure it was "LF". Which that just be "/n"? That's what I've tried and get the same results.

Comment: it is quite strange since i created a text file with `LF` as new line character to test, and the code above gave me exactly the result i expect: a `1x1 cell` which contains `nx1 cells` array. Maybe your text file contains other special ascii keys?